# reading UserDefaults before init() or inside of init()

Tags: ios, swift, iosdeployment

I'm having a problem getting my default_ip from my UserDefaults to a SocketManager.

```
final class Service: ObservableObject{    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.Scheduled-countdown.settings")
    let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://172.20.10.4:3000")!, config: [.log(false),.compress,.path("/ws")])

    init(){
        let default_ip = defaults?.string(forKey: "ip_adress") ?? "Nothing"
        let ipString : String = "http://\(default_ip):3000"
        //let manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: ipString)!, config: [.log(false),.compress,.path("/ws")])
        
        print(ipString)
        print(default_ip)
     }
}
```

if I have the SocketManager above init() it connects but I can't have the default_ip because above because it says

> Cannot use instance member 'defaults' within property initializer;
> property initializers run before 'self' is available

So how would I fix this?

I also uploaded the video to show the problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teqr20AnTVM

Comment: Didn't fix it.
I uploaded a video to youtube so you can see the problem.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=teqr20AnTVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to lazy var helped me.

```
final class Service: ObservableObject{    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.init(suiteName: "group.com.Scheduled-countdown.settings")
    lazy var default_ip = defaults?.string(forKey: "ip_adress") ?? "Nothing"
    lazy var ipString : String = "http://\(default_ip):3000"
    lazy var  manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: ipString)!, config: [.log(false),.compress,.path("/ws")])


    init(){
        print(ipString)
        print(default_ip)
     }
}
```